Ограничить максимальное качество выбора битрейта при автонастройке
https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/jsdoc/index.html
Использую данный плеер, технологию.
Столкнулась с тем, что если у видео максимальное качество 4К
И модуль определяет по пропускной способности воспроизвести в 4к. То он переключит на данное качество...
Трудность заключается в том, что к примеру при просмотре видео со сматфона.
Плеер переключил мне на высокое качество, пропускная способность позволяет, но телефон не в состоянии проигрывать данное видео. Постоянно какие та скризы, лаги...
Собственно вопрос, каким образом возможно определить какое какое качество способно проигрывать устройство пользователя?
Читая документацию, не могу найти информацию о том. Как мне выставить максимальное качество при автонастройке.
Хотя бы так, но лучше конечно. Сделать так, чтобы плеер определял подвисания или как говорят скризы в проигрывании. Дабы опустить качество при автонастройке...
